# Like to read single interface name from a list of interfaces returned by findall() in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read one interface name from a group of interface name which I'm getting after processing some text and if i want to read using list than getting output like below

```
['GigabitEthernet1/0/8']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/8']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/2']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/2']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/1']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/1']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/1']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/5']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/5']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/2']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/2']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/2']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/2']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/2']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/2']
['GigabitEthernet1/0/1']
```

this is the output when the code

`interfaces = RE_INT.findall(errormessage)`
`print interfaces`

And

```
GigabitEthernet1/0/8
GigabitEthernet1/0/8
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/1
GigabitEthernet1/0/1
GigabitEthernet1/0/1
GigabitEthernet1/0/5
GigabitEthernet1/0/5
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/1
```

when  `print interfaces[0]`

```
 `errormessage`  is the type

 <type 'str'>
 <type 'str'>
 <type 'str'>
 <type 'str'>
 <type 'str'>
```

and interfaces are the type

```
 <type 'list'>
 <type 'list'>
```

I would like to get GigabitEthernet1/0/8 using indexes

Please help!

Comment: It's not really clear what do you want to achieve. You have list of strings "interfaces", but what to you need further? You know about prefix "GigabitEthernet1" so you can just concatenate it with desired indexes, is it right?

Comment: This list is from s regex match and i want to use individual interface "GigabitEthernet1/0/8" and get some more information from the device

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand what you want but I will try:

You have this type of code:

```
for data in stream_of_log:
    interfaces = RE_INT.findall(errormessage)
    print interfaces
```

And what you want is (I hope):

```
interfaces = [RE_INT.findall(errormessage)[0] for data in stream_of_log]
```

So, you can access to data with this :

```
print interfaces
print interfaces[0]
print interfaces[3]
```

because you use findall which return a list, and what you want is only data on this list.

Comment: The Code snippet is below

Comment: datestamp, _, timestamp, _,  errorcode, _, errormessage =    matched.groups()
 if "UPDOWN:" in errorcode:
  if "down" in errormessage:
   interfaces = [RE_INT.findall(errormessage)[0] for data in errormessage]
    #print data[0] 
   print interfaces[2]       The result is the list of interfaces like below

Comment: GigabitEthernet1/0/8
GigabitEthernet1/0/8
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/1
GigabitEthernet1/0/1
GigabitEthernet1/0/1
GigabitEthernet1/0/5
GigabitEthernet1/0/5
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/1      where as i should have got GigabitEthernet1/0/2